# Android: how to put parameters in configuration files

Tags: android

I need to parametrize my app by adding, for example, the URL of a web service to be called. In other environments I would use a `.ini` file or a `web.config` file to store the info. How can this be achieved in Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For android you can store settings in a number of ways.  The simplest is [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).  You could also store the values in a sqlite database or use a ContentProvider.

To retrieve preferences, you do something like below.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String myURL = prefs.getString("url",defaultURL);
```

You can then set these from a [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) with some defaults provided in the XML that stores your preferences.

Comment: Is it the "standard" way to do it in Android? I would like simply to have a single pair key/value ... i find it too complex ...

Comment: This is the standard way to store preferences, especially between different activities in the same application.  These are effectively key/value pairs.  The PreferenceManager just handles the extra work of reading them from wherever they are stored, saving most of the work of saving them after they change, etc. so that you don't have to write boilerplate text file open/close/read code.  If you want, you can just store the value in a string in an xml as another person suggested and it would work fine if it does not need to change, but using SharedPreferences is the standard way.

Answer (score 5):

You can store the value in res/values/strings.xml as  `<string name="serviceUrl">http://www.example.com</string>`and pull it out in your activity using `getResources().getString(R.string.serviceUrl)`

This is not suitable for values which can be modified by the user. You should use the PreferenceManager in that case.

Answer (score 0):

could you store the details in an xml file and read them in ?
or possibly SharedPreferences ?
or an SQLITE database ?

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 possible ways.

1. Create a  system.properties file which is a simple text file and put all your configurations in that. Once done, put that file in asset folder and access it in your activity by using AssetManager.
2. Create a final class say Data.java and put all properties in that and access the properties in static way through out the application.

I recommend to go for option 2.